# c# web api Multiple actions were found that match the request issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add a new end point to already built application. I have these routes in my Global.asax.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   "MapByAction",
   "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   "Default", // Route name 
   "api/{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
   new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
);
```

My action are as follows

```
[HttpPost]
//[ActionName("MyChangePassword")]
[Route("MyChangePassword")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePassword([FromBody]UserChangePassword data)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

But when I call

> /api/myprofile/MyChangePassword

it confuses it with

```
[ActionName("logout")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Logout()
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you are using `route` try to change like this - `api/myprofile/MyChangePassword` refer @D-Shih answer. I'm suggesting same.

Comment: The Default route is prevailing. You must set the complete Route or change the routing

Comment: have you set up attribute routing in WebAPIConfig.cs

Comment: no I haven't. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a clearer route URL in the action attribute.

```
[Route("api/myprofile/MyChangePassword")]
```

Comment: You can try to use differnet RouteAttribute for those two actions

`[HttpPost]
[Route("api/myprofile/MyChangePassword")]
public IHttpActionResult ChangePassword([FromBody]UserChangePassword data)`
Logout action
`[ActionName("logout")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/myprofile/Logout")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Logout()`